# Is 'peaceful demonstration' an oxymoron?

Tags: meaning

Oh, we know the standards: Jumbo Shrimp, Real Phony,Living Dead..... is *peaceful demonstration* in the list: reasons why/not are, of course unexpectedly anticipated.

Comment: I don't think the word "demonstration" implies something non-peaceful. Technically speaking, showing off your science fair project is a demonstration. Unless you were building bombs, those are probably pretty peaceful.

Comment: And you are building bombs and demonstrating them *to me*, I hope your demonstrations are either peaceful or at a great distance.

Comment: http://www.clickorlando.com/news/8755909/detail.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Peaceful demonstration' is *not* an oxymoron.  There is nothing inherent in the definition of 'demonstration' that suggests order or chaos--a demonstration can be either. Describing a demonstration as 'peaceful' sets that demonstration apart from one that is 'chaotic', or even 'riotous'.

Here are a few more adjectives that are commonly associated with 'demonstration' that delineate one type of demonstration from another:

- Quiet
- Classroom
- Ceremonial
- Religious
- Political
- Military (not the same as riotous)

ngrams.google.com produces this nice graphic demonstration that underscores my point.

[image]

**Edit:** Created a new graph that includes 'violent demonstration'

[image]

Comment: I'd call the opposite of a peaceful demonstration *violent*.

Comment: I'm not sure that 'violent' is always the opposite of 'peaceful'.  A boxing match may be considered to be a 'violent demonstration' even when the audience members are orderly.

Comment: I'm not sure what a boxing match has to do with this: what I'm trying to say is that the opposite of *peaceful [political] demonstration* is *violent [political] demonstration*, not *riotous [political] demonstration*.

Comment: +1, although I still maintain that an oxymoron is only so when the definitions of the elements that make up the word contradict each other.  Whether or not the _object represented by the word_ is an oxymoron is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

*Peaceful Demonstration* is only an oxymoron in repressive countries, where regardless of the intent of the demonstrators, the government shows up and initiates violence.  Ordinarily[*] it is entirely possible to put your political opinions on display in a peaceful manner.

[*]: speaking from a modern, US-centric viewpoint; world history may make me a liar.

Comment: Unless my comprehension of the definition of an oxymoron is lacking (which is certainly possible), I can't help but think that it is, under no circumstances, an oxymoron.  Even in instances where a "peaceful demonstration" turns aggressive, the definition of the word remains unchanged and thus can't be an oxymoron.  _Jumbo shrimp_ is an oxymoron because the definition is self-contradicting... not individual instances of the objects it represents.  There is, in fact, nothing self-contradicting about an actual instance of a jumbo shrimp. (just the definition)

Comment: In a country where a demonstration is, by definition, a violent thing, a "peaceful demonstration" would indeed be a self-contradicting term.

Comment: ok... I see your point.  If you edit your answer I'll take back my -1  (it won't let me take it back unless the answer is edited)

Comment: Invisible edit made.  :-)

Comment: ok - I changed it to +1

Answer (score 2):

Why oxymoron?

*a public display of group feelings (usually of a political nature)*
can be very peaceful. People can sit totally quiet

And Shrimp: *any of various edible decapod crustaceans*

Just because a person who is deemed shrimp sized is small, does not mean that a huge shrimp cannot be called jumbo...

Comment: I would argue that _jumbo shrimp_ is definitely an oxymoron.  There exists a definition of "shrimp" that essentially means _small_ or _small person._  The _small person_ definition is often used on non-personal objects via personification.  It's good enough for me, at least.

Comment: But a Jumbo Shrimp is only ever used about actual decapod crustaceans. I am sure I can find other examples where using one of the definitions of a word with an attribute makes it an oxymoron and another not.

Comment: Jumbo Shrimp is more of a pun+oxymoron=old joke. Don't think about it too hard; it is now ingrained in the public conscious as a de facto oxymoron.

Comment: Agreed.  People think of "small" when they think of the word "shrimp."  Then you slap on the word "jumbo" and now it's oxymoronic.

Comment: jumbo shrimp is, of course, an oxymoron.  an xoymoron is an **apparently** contradictory phrase.  if (for some reason) a real-world "thing" arises, the **phrase** is still an oxymoron.